# how to find('some text') from a particular offset after read() from a file

Tags: python

I have opened a file f = open("somefile.txt", "r")
then read in into a variable as data = f.read(), now when I use data.find('sometext') it gives/shows offset of the first occurrence in somefile.txt, if the 'sometext' repeated twice in the somefile.txt I am not able to go to second one. so I wanted to find() from particular offset, could you please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get all (i.e. even overlapping) matches:

```
 [i for i in range(len(data)) if string.startswith('sometext', i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion using `re.finditer` which seems really appropriate to find the start index of any occurrence of a substring:

```
import re

s = "sometext someothertext sometext sometext someothertext some text someothertext"
result = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('sometext', s)]

print(result)  # [0, 23, 32]
```